# Review Policy in MechanicalTurk

Tags: python, boto, mechanicalturk

Is there a way to set an `AssignmentReview` or `HITReview` Policy in Boto? In looking it up, I came across this post, but this is from two years ago: https://github.com/boto/boto/issues/1452.

Is there code reference to add a Review policy for a HIT in boot or elsewhere?